# How do I position a DOM element in the exact same position no matter the screen size?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to add some input boxes that should always be in the same position, but when I view the webpage in my macbook the input box is a different location than if I view it with my bigger monitor. What is the best way to tackle this? Here is a jsfiddle of what more or less I'm trying to do.

```
<input name="arrive" type="date" placeholder="Arrival date:">

input[name="arrive"] {
    position: absolute;
    width: 16.9em;
    top: 18vw;
    left: 15vw;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/8mn5cdwt/1/

Comment: How about setting pixel values (`top: 200px` for example) instead of using vw

Comment: ... or you can use `vh` instead of `vw` on `top` so the difference between devices is smaller.

Answer (score 1):

Viewport Width (vw) unit is based on the width of the viewport. You need to specify position in pixels, not in vw:

```
<input name="arrive" type="date" placeholder="Arrival date:">

// 180 and 150 are your values in pixels (you need to replace them 
// with what you need)
input[name="arrive"] {
    position: absolute;
    width: 16.9em;
    top: 180px;
    left: 150px;
}
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for your reply! My problem is, that if I use vw, em, px when I view my webpage the position of the input tag is in a different position than if I view it from my monitor, and I would like this to be equal for all different screen sizes.

Comment: I used px for absolute positioning of input here https://jsfiddle.net/vadim_/t785uhmL and after changing screen width/height, the input is in the same position. Maybe you meant something different by `input boxes that should always be in the same position`. Please elaborate.

Answer (score 0):

`vw` refers to the width of the viewport. If your viewport width is 1920px, then your `top` is now 0.18*1920px = 345.6px; and if it is 720px, it will change to 129.6px.

Also I'm not sure about your problem, but usually when setting `top`, you would use `vh` (viewport height).

Try using pixels to set the position. e.g. `top: 120px;`